# Understanding the `optimize` function

Tags: r, optimization

I'm new to R and my question is of a beginner.

I have

```
kappa <- c(0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999)
```

I don't understand why

```
var_optim <- sapply(kappa, function(t) 
  optimize(function(x) abs(FX_fun(x) - t), c(-2,2))$minimum)
```

works fine but

```
var_optim <- optimize(function(x) abs(FX_fun(x) - kappa), c(-2,2))$minimum
```

doesn't

What's the difference between the two expressions because I was thinking the two of them are the same

I received a response telling me that in my first statement t is a scalar while it is not in my second statement.

In fact, I don't understand how t is a scalar in my first statement. Because with my understanding for it to be a scalar what we should write is

var_optim <- sapply(1:length (kappa), function(t) optimize(function(x) abs(FX_fun(x) - kappa[i] ), c(-2,2))$minimum)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kappa` is a vector, while `t` in your first statement is a scalar. I assume `FX_fun(x)` is also a scalar, so computing `abs(FX_fun(x)-t)` is also a scalar, and optimize will see a scalar-valued function, that it will happily optimize.

On the other hand, in the second statement `FX_fun(x)-kappa` is also a vector: scalar minus vector works in R, it just does the subtraction on every element of `kappa`, and the result is a vector. But now optimize sees a vector-valued function, and obviously it can't optimize this.

---

Here is how sapply works: `sapply(v, f)` takes a function `f` and a vector `v`, applies `f` to eash element of `v`, and builds a vector `w` with the results. That is, mathematically `w(i)=f(v(i))`, but `f` only ever takes scalar values as arguments (the elements of `v`, one by one).

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why t in my first statement is a scalar. Won't t take the value of kappa ? I mean what I did is : var_optim <- sapply(kappa, function(t) optimize(function(x) abs(FX_fun(x) - t), c(-2,2))$minimum) and not var_optim <- sapply(1:length (kappa), function(i) optimize(function(x) abs(FX_fun(x) - kappa[i] ), c(-2,2))$minimum) so I thought the first statement shouldn't work either –

Comment: The values of `kappa` are number (scalars). So, `t`, which takes the values of `kappa` one by one, has always a scalar value. I updated the answer. Looping on the values is exactly equivalent to looping on `i` and take the value `kappa[i]`. Consider also the `for` loop in R: it does never loop on integers, but always on values of a vector. It's `for (x in v)`. The notation `1:n` is only syntactic sugar to denote the vector `c(1, ..., n)`. The same happens to `sapply` (and often you don't need the actual index).